# jquery->iframe ignores script tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

Because jquery UI draggable is interfering with the clicks I thought i'd put the video in an iframe. The video works however I notice the javascript isn't kicking in. It appears the script tag isn't being added (according to firefox and chrome DOM). Why?

```
function LoadVideo(IFrameForVideoDom, videourl, posterUrl) {
    var ibody = $($(IFrameForVideoDom)[0].contentWindow.document).find('body');
    ibody.css("border", "none");
    var sz = '<scr'+'ipt src="/javascripts/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js">'+'</scr'+'ipt><link rel="stylesheet" href="/javascripts/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.css" />';
    ibody.html(sz+'<video src="' + videourl + '" controls="controls" preload="none" poster="' + posterUrl + '"></video>');
}
```

Comment: some html code will be helpful

Comment: ... are you kidding @Dolours? It iframe doesnt have html which is why i'm replacing all of the body